# OR operator in Drupal View Filters

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

I need to implement an OR operator between some filters in a Drupal View.
By default, Drupal AND's every filter together.

By using

```
hook_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query)
```

I can access the query ( var $query ) , and I can change either :

```
$query->where[0]['type']
```

to 'OR', or

```
$query->group_operator
```

to 'OR'

The problem is however, that I do not need OR's everywhere. I've tried changing both of them to OR seperately, and it doesn't yield the desired result.

It seems changing those values, puts OR's everywhere, while I need => ( filter 1 AND filter 2 ) OR ( filter 3 ), so just 1 OR.

I could just check the Query of the View, copy it, modify it, and run it through db_query, but that's just dirty ..

Any suggestions ?

Thx in advance.

Comment: As a second though to this, there is also using the query alter for the view -- I'm going to try this route. http://www.brianfending.com/content/better-wheres-your-drupal-forums-hookviewsqueryalter

Comment: The query alter is what @Vodde is referring to as 'dirty', we are trying to modify the query clauses via a Views API call.

Comment: Would be nice to specify Drupal and Views versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want do it with view_query_alter hook, you should use $query->add_where() where you can specify if it's AND or OR. From views/include/query.inc

```
  /**
   * Add a simple WHERE clause to the query. The caller is responsible for
   * ensuring that all fields are fully qualified (TABLE.FIELD) and that
   * the table already exists in the query.
   *
   * @param $group
   *   The WHERE group to add these to; groups are used to create AND/OR
   *   sections. Groups cannot be nested. Use 0 as the default group.
   *   If the group does not yet exist it will be created as an AND group.
   * @param $clause
   *   The actual clause to add. When adding a where clause it is important
   *   that all tables are addressed by the alias provided by add_table or
   *   ensure_table and that all fields are addressed by their alias wehn
   *   possible. Please use %d and %s for arguments.
   * @param ...
   *   A number of arguments as used in db_query(). May be many args or one
   *   array full of args.
   */
  function add_where($group, $clause)
```

Comment: I tried it myself and using this method results in `( filter 1 OR filter 2 ) AND ( filter 3 OR fliter 4 )`, which is opposed to what we are looking for: `( filter 1 AND filter 2 ) OR ( filter 3 AND filter 4 )`.

Answer (score 12):

If you are using Views 3 / Drupal 7 and looking for the answer to this question, it is baked right into Views. Where it says "add" next to filters, click the dropdown, then click "and/or; rearrange". It should be obvious from there.

Comment: +1 for this, It does exactly what I needed. also look at field groups once you get there. That was the only part that took me a few minutes to realize

Comment: I have Views 3, and I don't see "and/or;" just "rearrange"?

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately this is still a missing feature in Views2. [It has long been asked for](http://drupal.org/node/118672) and was promised a while ago, but seems to be a tricky piece of work and [is now scheduled for Views3](http://drupal.org/node/118672#comment-1775712).

In the meantime you could try the [Views Or](http://drupal.org/project/views_or) module mentioned in that thread. As of today, it is still in dev status, but seems to be actively maintained and [the issue queue](http://drupal.org/project/issues/search/views_or?text=&assigned=&submitted=&participant=&status[]=Open&issue_tags=) does not look to bad, so you might want to give it a try.

Comment: +1 That this is not in Views2. `$this->query->where[$group]['type'] = 'OR';` does not work, and `$this->query->group_operator = 'OR';` converts all the operators between WHERE clauses to OR. Very frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

I added it by concatenating the string.

It is relatively specific to the implementation - people would need to play with field to match for OR - node.title in the following code and the field to match it with - node_revisions.body in this case.

Extra piece of code to make sure that node_revisions.body is in the query.

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_views_api().
 */
function eventsor_views_api() { // your module name into hook_views_api
  return array(
  'api' => 2,
  // might not need the line below, but in any case, the last arg is the name of your module
  'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'eventsor'),
 );
}

/**
 *
 * @param string $form
 * @param type $form_state
 * @param type $form_id 
 */
function eventsor_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {

  switch ($view->name) {
    case 'Events':
      _eventsor_composite_filter($query);
      break;
  }
}

/**
 * Add to the where clause.
 * @param type $query 
 */
function _eventsor_composite_filter(&$query) {
  // If we see "UPPER(node.title) LIKE UPPER('%%%s%%')" - then add and to it.
  if (isset($query->where)) {

    $where_count = 0;
    foreach ($query->where as $where) {
      $clause_count = 0;
      if (isset($where['clauses'])) {
        foreach ($where['clauses'] as $clause) {
          $search_where_clause = "UPPER(node.title) LIKE UPPER('%%%s%%')";
          // node_data_field_long_description.field_long_description_value
          $desirable_where_clause = "UPPER(CONCAT_WS(' ', node.title, node_revisions.body)) LIKE UPPER('%%%s%%')";
          if ($clause == $search_where_clause) {
            //  $query->add_where('or', 'revisions.body = %s'); - outside of what we are looking for
            $query->where[$where_count]['clauses'][$clause_count] = $desirable_where_clause;

            // Add the field to the view, just in case.
            if (!isset($query->fields['node_revisions_body'])) {
              $query->fields['node_revisions_body'] = array(
                'field' => 'body',
                'table' => 'node_revisions',
                'alias' => 'node_revisions_body'
              );
            }
          }
          $clause_count++;
        }
      }
      $where_count++;
    }
  }
}
```