# Adding a JOIN statement in hook_views_query_alter()

Tags: php, sql, drupal, drupal-6

I need to modify a query Views generates so that I can use highly custom filters. I have implemented the add_where() function with some ORs thanks to this question: [OR operator in Drupal View Filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340423/or-operator-in-drupal-view-filters)

However this only solves a part of my problem. There are some fields that I cannot filter on because I need to have extra JOINs in my query.

Is there something along the lines of

```
$view->query->add_where()
```

that can insert JOIN statements?

Comment: Well, there is `$view->query->add_table()` and `$view->query->add_relationship()`, but their usage, relation and preconditions are not obvious from the code (at least not for me). Can't you just add the relationships via the Views UI to ensure that your needed tables get joined in?

Comment: @Henrik After digging into the query.inc file in the views module, I found the functions you mentioned. There isn't much to go on aside from the comments, so usage is somewhat vague. Also, make your comment an answer so i can accept it.

Comment: Yup, usage is not obvious, and the documentation is lacking - I have not tried to use them either, so I can not really help with that. Turned comment to answer as suggested - thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there is `$view->query->add_table()` and `$view->query->add_relationship()` (in the views_query class in 'includes/query.inc'), but their usage, relation and preconditions are not obvious from the code (at least not for me).

Maybe you could add the relationships via the Views UI to ensure that your needed tables get joined in.

---

(Note: Comment turned to answer, as no better idea showed up :/

Comment: Actually, adding another relationship in the views UI did work for me. All I had to do was look at the generated query from views to find out what table was needed to go into the add_where function. hooray!

Answer (score 5):

I found an answer [here](https://api.drupal.org/comment/54213#comment-54213). Shameless copy:

```
function hook_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
    $join = new views_join();
    $join->table = 'my_table';
    $join->field = 'my_field';
    $join->left_table = 'left_table';
    $join->left_field = 'left_field';
    $join->type = 'left';
    $join->extra = array(
        array(
            'field' => 'bundle',
            'value' => 'user',
        )
    );
    $query->add_relationship('relationship_name', $join, 'node');
}
```