# Add view filter to retrieve content associated with one or more Taxonomy Term IDs

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views, drupal-taxonomy, drupal-contextual-filters

I have created a Drupal 6 view which has two "Taxonomy: Term" (Term ID) filters, for two different taxonomy terms. I need to create a feed that pulls content that is associated with a OR b, or that is associated with a AND b. Currently, nothing is displayed because it seems that the logic of two filters is AND, not OR.

How do you pull content that has the logic OR with Drupal views?

It does work if there is only one filter, but as soon as I add a second filter, zero records are found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OR filter is not built in to Views2.  For ways to get around this, see http://groups.drupal.org/node/16173. And this old post might help as well [OR operator in Drupal View Filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340423/or-operator-in-drupal-view-filters)