# How to use views argument in drupal?

Tags: drupal-views

I am using views arguments for filtering jobs list.

I am taking state as argument.

Previously, state argument was accepting single value and it was filtering jobs correctly.

Now I made state field multivalued it means it accepts multiple states as input separated by comma.

here is my code for assigning arguments

```
$arg[0]=$filters['title_nodes'];
$arg[1]=$filters['company'];
$arg[2]=$filters['city'];
$arg[3]=$filters['state'];
$arg[4]=$filters['zip'];
$arg[5]=$filters['types'];
$arg[6]=$filters['categories'];
$arg[7]=$filters['industries'];
$arg[8]=$filters['beverages'];
$arg[9]=$filters['user'];
```

previously,  `$arg[3]=$filters['state'];` this $arg[3] is filled with single state as New York etc. and for single value filter was working fine.

now, 
`$arg[3]=$filters['state']`; this argument is containing multiple states.

because of multiple states jobs are not getting filtered.

now suppose we entered 3 states, then in `$arg[3]` 3 states get stored and for each job,

argument checks whether there is any job who is having all 3 states in single job which is not possible.

Now how can I make this filter works for multiple states??

Thanks in advance.

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Did you find the answer for this by now?

I think you might need to change the operator of your condition from AND to OR via the view_query_alter hook. There are already multiple posts on how to accomplish this such as [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340423/or-operator-in-drupal-view-filters)